# Parse huge text files and identify poorly delimited columns on each row

Tags: python, sql, regex, database, pandas

I am parsing huge text files (3GB each) with millions of rows.
I am reading the files using pandas' read_table, including an iterator, and without specifying a delimiter, because sep = " " keeps giving me following error:

> CParserError: Error tokenizing data

A typical row for example:

```
 <www.blabla.com> <mmm> "Hello" <A.C> .
```

I wrote a function that will return a list with the following elements:

```
 www.blabla.com     mmm    Hello    A.C
```

But it gets complicated because text outside <> or "" must be ignored.  Sometimes there are double quotes inside the quotes that are escaped with the backslash (\"), and sometimes the brackets are replaced by _:mexx for a mysterious reason i do not understand, but in which case it counts.

Writing above conditions into a function made the script very very slow. Took me more than two hours to process ten million rows, and i must process approx 200 million rows.

My goal is not the text per se, but to count the elements on each row.
It could be either three or four. So i decided to use only native functions to pandas and avoid applying. Here is the relevant code so far:

```
tdf = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['TOPIC', 'COUNTER'])
chunkk = 50000
for ii, f in enumerate(files):
    reader = pd.read_table(f, header=None,  chunksize = chunkk)
    for df in reader:
        df = df[0].str.split(" ", expand=True)
        df['TOPIC'] = df[0] #first element retrieved from split
        # count here across the row the number of elements
        tdf = tdf.append(df[['TOPIC', 'COUNTER']], ignore_index=True)

    tdf = tdf.groupby('TOPIC', as_index=False).sum()
    i += chunkk
    print("Completed " + str(i) + " rows from file #" + str(ii +1))
```

I think i need to use .count(axis =1) but i am not sure how to do it. Looking at pandas documentation http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html
i think regex could be a key solution.

Any advice on how to count the number of valid elements is greatly appreciated. Also ANY advice to make the code run faster would be great.
There might be a better way to do it using a database and SQL so i am tagging them below.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few options you might have.  I am not sure which is best for your use.  I am thinking distribute and process with Pyspark would probably be my assumption.  However.....

1. I am not sure putting this in a SQL database would give you anything.  You would still have to parse the data and process it so even if we could optimize the querying, you have other issues.
2. You may want to take a close look at disk access vs memory.  If the file is small enough to easily fit in memory, you may get better performance by reading the whole thing and then processing it line by line.  This would improve performance from disk I/O but at a steep memory cost.
3. You could distribute, load at once, and process in Pyspark.  This may be the best option since you are just looking at analyzing data and getting an answer back,